# weight initialization in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, scipy, neural-network

I've come across the "truncated normal" weight initialization technique while using Keras for my deep learning project. I understand that it is one of the options available for initializing the weights in certain layers, but I'm unsure about its advantages and when it is most suitable to use.

Could someone explain how the "truncated normal" weight initialization works in Keras? What sets it apart from other initialization methods, such as "glorot_uniform" and "he_uniform"? Are there specific scenarios or network architectures where truncated normal initialization tends to perform better or worse?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that this constant "balances back" the variance shrinking from truncation. An untruncated normal distribution with mean 0 and stddev 1 should produce a distribution with stddev 1. Truncation eliminates the outlier, shrinking the stddev for the output values to < 1. This leads to a smaller stddev for the weight initialization for e.g. glorot, which could be sensitive to changes in the distribution.
To get a truncated distribution with stddev 1 for the output values(!), the stddev for the distribtuion to draw from has to increase to counter the re-drawing of outliers. Thats why they divide by 0.879.